# Problem either with number of characters exceeding cell limit, or storing lists of variable length

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv, large-files

The problem:

I have lists of genes expressed in 53 different tissues. Originally, this data was stored in a maximal array of the genes, with 'NaN' where there was no expression. I am trying to create new lists for each tissue that just have the genes expressed, as it was very inefficient to be searching through this array every time I was running my script. I have a code that finds the genes for each tissue as required, but I do not know how to store the ouptut.

I was using pandas data frame, and then converting to csv. But this does not accept lists of varying length, unless I put this list as a single item. However, then when I save the data frame to a csv, it tries to squeeze this very long list (all genes exprssed for one tissue) into a single cell. I get an error of the string length exceeding the excel character-per-cell limit.

Therefore I need a way of either dealing with this limit, or stroing my lists in a different way. I would rather just have one file for all lists.

My code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np


#Import list of tissues:
df = pd.read_csv(r'E-MTAB-5214-query-results.tsv', skiprows = [0,1,2,3], sep='\t')
tissuedict=df.to_dict()
tissuelist = list(tissuedict.keys())[2:]

all_genes = [gene for key,gene in tissuedict['Gene Name'].items()]

data = []


for tissue in tissuelist:

    #Create array to keep track of the protein mRnaS in tissue that are not present in the network
    #initiate with first tissue, protein

    nanInd = [key for key,value in tissuedict[tissue].items() if math.isnan(value)]

    tissueExpression = np.delete(all_genes, nanInd)

    datatis = [tissue, tissueExpression.tolist()]

    print(datatis)

    data.append(datatis)


print(data)


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_csv(r'tissue_expression_data.csv')
```

Link to data (either one):

https://github.com/joanna-lada/gene_data/blob/master/E-MTAB-5214-query-results.tsv

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joanna-lada/gene_data/master/E-MTAB-5214-query-results.tsv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need lists of the gene names found in each tissue. This writes these lists as columns into a csv:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('E-MTAB-5214-query-results.tsv', skiprows = [0,1,2,3], sep='\t')
df = df.drop(columns='Gene ID').set_index('Gene Name')

res = pd.DataFrame()
for c in df.columns:
    res = pd.concat([res, pd.Series(df[c].dropna().index, name=c)], axis=1)

res.to_csv('E-MTAB-5214-query-results.csv', index=False)
```

(Writing them as rows would have been easier, but Excel can't import so many columns)
Don't open the csv in Excel directly, but use a blank worksheet and import the csv (Data - External data, From text), otherwise you can't separate them into Excel columns in one run (at least in Excel 2010).

[image]

Comment: Hi Stef, thank you for your suggestion. I have tried this, but I don't quite get the output. The list of 53 tissues is in cell A1, and cells up to A33000 are filled with lists. Thrse cannot correspond to the tissues lists as there are only 53 tissues!

Comment: I added a picture of how the result looks like: 53 columns with max 33061 rows (pyhton 3.7.3, pandas 0.25.0 - what versions do you have?)

Comment: How did you do the import? Go to Data, then External Data - From text, then the text conversion assistant opens, you pick "separated" (should be chose by defaultm then "next", then tick **separator = comma**, then finish. (I'm on a German version of Excel, so the exact English names might differ a bit)

Comment: I see! The separator had somehow changed to tab!

Answer (score 0):

create your `data` variable as a dictionary 
you can save the dictionary to a json file using json.dump [refer here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage)

```
import json

data = {}
for tissue in tissuelist:
    nanInd = [key for key,value in tissuedict[tissue].items() if math.isnan(value)]
    tissueExpression = np.delete(all_genes, nanInd)
    data[tissue] =  tissueExpression.tolist()

with open('filename.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This doesn't seem to have header however? I would like to read the lists acording to the headers (tissue names). I have checked the documentation and there is no 'header' option. I'm not exactly sure if the skpkeys does the same.

Comment: In fact, the output is a bit strange. There aren't any 'gene names'!